# Newbie: forgotten root password for Arch and tried to use bash as init method but /bin/bash_ does not exist

Tags: arch-linux

I tried to follow these instructions https://www.tecmint.com/reset-forgotten-root-password-in-arch-linux/ but after I pressed ctrl+x to boot into single-user mode with the root filesystem mounted I received the prompt:

ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /bin/bash_ does not exist. Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

Also, whatever I type in after the # returns sh: : not found.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure there is a root password?  Modern Linux distributions make the first user a member of admin group and sudo "commmand" runs from this user (authenticate when asked).

Comment: Well when I turn on it asks for login and password, the login is root but I forgot the password. I could try not typing in any password but I can't get out of this interface now. Whatever I type after [rootfs ] # blablabla just returns sh: blablabla: not found

A friend helped me install arch linux and I haven't used it in a while and I'm new to it. So I'm stuck here currently.

Comment: It appears that I do need a password. I pressed enter and gives Login incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The `_` is not part of the path and should not be typed in. (It's the GRUB input cursor.)

Comment: I see, then what does "Bailing out, you are on your own." mean here?

Comment: It means that the initramfs considers this a fatal error (which it is – you're telling it to launch a nonexistent init) and can't continue the boot process. Without initramfs (with root= and init= options being processed by the kernel), in this situation you'd just see a "kernel panic" crash. With an initramfs in use (where the kernel starts the initramfs "/init" first, which then starts the main init) there are more options available – the initramfs shell that you're getting dropped into actually has _some_ basic tools in its /bin – so it's telling you to try to fix the problem somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This helped!